# C++ fstream always fails on .txt file

Tags: c++, c, stream

my .exe and addrr.txt files are located on D:\ drive

when im trying to ready .txt file ifstream does nothing

this is my code:

```
 ifstream file;
        file.open("addrr.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            while (file.good())
            {
                cout << "Addrr.txt IsGood" <<endl;
                getline(file, Path);
            }

            file.close();
        }
```

sorry for such dumb question. im noob

Comment: Are you running the program in D:\ ? If not, change the filename name "addrr.txt" to "D:\addrr.txt"

Comment: they are at the same location(D:\test.exe, D:\addrr.txt)

Comment: what directory are you in when you run your program?

Comment: am calling it from browser so directory is: C:\\Program Files......

Comment: I think as user315052 has correctly identified, try running it from D: itself or alternatively change the file path in the program to D:\addrr.txt

Comment: This is one of those cases where you fire up Process Monitor - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx and just determine what file is being looked for on the fopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

To make sure that the file `addrr.txt` can be found during runtime of the application you need to

- specify the absolute path to the file, i.e. `D:\addrr.txt`, or
- specify the relative path from the current working directory (CWD), which is `C:\Program Files\Mozilla FireFox` apparantly. (Which is impractical if the file is located on another partition.)

The CWD is usually the directory from which the application is run. If you'd run your application in `D:` it should work. (Your application may well change the CWD at runtime (e.g. by use of `chdir()`, or `SetCurrentDirectory()`). However, usually it is more appropriate to specify the absolute path to the files or to place the files in the correct relative location to the CWD.)

---

This compiles and runs fine for me:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  ifstream file;
  file.open("addrr.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out);
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    while (file.good())
    {
      string Path;
      cout << "Addrr.txt IsGood" <<endl;
      getline(file, Path);
      cout << Path << endl;
    }
    file.close();
  }
}

// output similar to:
/*
Addrr.txt IsGood
addrr.txt
Addrr.txt IsGood
addrr.txt
Addrr.txt IsGood
addrr.txt
Addrr.txt IsGood

Addrr.txt IsGood

*/


// file: addrr.txt
/*
addrr.txt
addrr.txt
addrr.txt

*/
```

---

Is your filename correct (i.e. case sensitively speaking)? Do you run your application from the path where the executable is located (s.t. the file is located in the current working directory)?

Comment: my .exe file opening from browser and path is C:\Program Files\Mozilla FireFox.

Comment: +1, but "current working directory is usually the directory from which the application is called" is rather imprecise. It is defined by the calling process, i.e. browser, explorer, `cmd.exe` etc. In the common cases from Windows Explorer it is the directory the application is in, for `cmd.exe` it is the directory in the prompt, when executing through link it is specified as property of the link. In other cases like FireFox, well, you have to know what that program does.